# Issue Filtering Out Old records from reports

Tags: sql

I am working on a query that is support to return the update date of a document and the most recent data input for a certain field.

I am having an issue with pulling the Most RECENT update date from the query.

The report should be pulling in the Most Recent Update Date (Column 2), The Historical Customer Req Ship date for that document that was updated on that day, as well as other data in the system.

The issue I am having is that it is pulling in data for every time the document was updated (SO Update Date Column #2) instead of the most recent. In my example below, it should be pulling in the most recent update date of 05152019 and return 13 lines versus 400

```
    select 
    DISTINCT(T0.DocNum) 'S/O No', 
    T0.DocDate 'SO Date',
    S0.Updatedate as 'SO Date Update Date',
    S0.U_CustReqShipDate as 'History Customer Req ship date',
    Datediff(d,S0.U_CustReqShipDate, S0.updatedate)  as 'Days Between Update Date and Customer Req 
    Ship Date',
    Case When Datediff(d,S0.U_CustReqShipDate,S0.updatedate) <= '3' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' end as 
    'Falls within Date Parameters',
    T1.ItemCode as 'Part Number', 
    T1.Dscription as 'Part Description',
     DATEDIFF(d, T0.DocDate, T1.U_CustReqShipDate) as 'Days Between DocDate & Cust Req Ship Date',
     T5.U_LeadTimeWks as 'Part Number Lead Time in Wks',
    (T5.U_LeadTimeWks*7) as 'Part Number Lead Time In Days',
    (DATEDIFF(d, T0.DocDate, T1.U_CustReqShipDate) - (T5.U_LeadTimeWks*7)) as 'Days Between Lead 
     Time & Calculate Days B/w DocDate & CustReq ShipDate',
     CASE WHEN  (DATEDIFF(d, T0.DocDate, T1.U_CustReqShipDate) >= (T5.U_LeadTimeWks*7)) THEN 
     'CRD>=LT'
      WHEN (DATEDIFF(d, T0.DocDate, T1.U_CustReqShipDate) < (T5.U_LeadTimeWks*7)) THEN 'CRD<LT'
      ELSE '' END AS 'Ship Date VS Lead Time',
      T1.U_ActualShipDate as 'Actual Ship Date',
      T1.U_SupPromShipDate as 'MSD Date',
       DATEDIFF(d, T1.U_SupPromShipDate, T1.U_ActualShipDate) as 'On Time Ship Days - MSD',
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, T1.U_SupPromShipDate, T1.U_ActualShipDate) <= 0 /*and  DATEDIFF(d, 
    T1.U_SupPromShipDate, T1.U_ActualShipDate) <= 2*/ then 'YES' 
     ELSE 'NO' END AS 'On Time Delivery - MSD',
    T1.U_CustReqShipDate as 'CRD Date',
     DATEDIFF(d, T1.U_CustReqShipDate, T1.U_ActualShipDate) as 'On Time Ship Days - CRD',
     CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, T1.U_CustReqShipDate, T1.U_ActualShipDate) <= 0 /*and  DATEDIFF(d, 
    T1.U_CustReqShipDate, T1.U_ActualShipDate) <= 2*/ then 'YES' 
    ELSE 'NO' END AS 'On Time Delivery - CRD',
    T0.DocStatus, 
    T4.DocNum 'Delivery No'
    , Convert(date, getdate(),112) 'As Of Date'



     FROM
     ORDR T0
     Inner Join RDR1 T1 on T0.Docentry = T1.Docentry
      Left Join DLN1 T3 ON T3.BaseENTRY = T1.DOCENTRY AND T1.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode and T1.LineNum = 
     T3.BaseLine
     Left Join ODLN T4 ON T4.DOCENTRY = T3.DOCENTRY
     inner JOIN dbo.[@LEAD_TIMES] T5 on T1.itemcode = T5.U_PartNumber
     left join (Select DISTINCT(S0.updatedate), MAX(S1.LogInstanc) as 'Max Log', 
      S1.U_CustReqShipDate, S0.DocNUM, S0.docentry

      from RDR1 S3
      left JOIN ORDR S2 on S3.docentry = S2.docentry
      left JOIN ADOC S0 on S3.docentry = S0.docentry AND S2.docentry = S3.docentry and S3.ObjType = 
         S0.ObjType
         left JOIN ADO1 S1  on S1.docentry = S0.docentry and S1.LogInstanc-1 = S0.loginstanc-1 and 
         S1.linenum = S3.LineNum and S1.itemcode = S3.itemcode and S1.U_CustReqShipDate <> 
           S3.U_CustReqShipDate and S3.docentry = S1.DocEntry
           WHERE S1.U_CustReqShipDate is NOT NULL
           Group By S0.updatedate, S1.U_CustReqShipDate, S0.docentry, S0.DocNum) as S0 on 
        T0.docentry = S0.docentry and T1.U_CustReqShipDate <> S0.U_CustReqShipDate


    WHERE /*isnull(T4.Docnum,'')<> ''*/ isnull(T1.U_ActualShipDate,'') <> '' /*and T0.DocStatus = 
    'C'*/ and T0.CANCELED <> 'Y' and  T1.U_LineStatus <> 'C' and /*T0.DocDate*/ T1.U_ActualShipDate 
      between convert(date, dateadd(year, -1, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()),0)),112) and 
      convert(date, dateadd(dd,-1, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate())+1,0)),112) and T0.U_SOType 
       = 'Sales Order'
       AND T0.ObjType = '17'  and T0.docnum = '35096'

    Group By
    T0.DocNum, 
    T0.DocDate,
    T1.ItemCode, 
    T1.Dscription,
    T1.U_ActualShipDate,
    T1.U_SupPromShipDate,
    T1.U_CustReqShipDate,
    T0.DocStatus, 
    T4.DocNum,
    T5.U_LeadTimeWks,
    S0.U_CustReqShipDate,
    S0.UpdateDate
```

/*
Need to add history checck to determine when CRD date is updated.  Show what date CRD was updated (update date), show if new CRD Date is 3 or less days from the updated date. 
*/

Comment: Write a subquery to find the `MAX` update date. Inner join your subquery to your main query on your ORDR primary key field (Docentry?).

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `select 
    DISTINCT T0.DocNum ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: You rarely never combine GROUP BY with SELECT DISTINCT, since GROUP BY eliminates duplicates.